# Inno setup read REG_BINARY value from registry

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I am trying to read REG_BINARY value from registry in inno setup. I am using following code. I am not getting any error but it straight away falls out of the if loop. I am not sure where I am going wrong and what I am missing here. it looks pretty straight forward though.

```
var
  V: ansistring;
Begin
  if RegQueryBinaryValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Data\Sql', 'value', V) then
  MsgBox('Value is "' + V + '"', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Where do I file the bug?

Comment: I can reproduce it with `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId` in Inno Setup 5.5.4 (u). Please file a bug about it (if there is not one already).

Comment: Yes, I think it's required.

Comment: @TLama: The issue I raised was closed telling me to use the newsgroup for questions. Could you please raise this issue in appropriate place?

Comment: So finally it was me who made a mistake (I'm switching between 64 and 32-bit systems). Sorry for that. If you are not running a 64-bit mode of Inno Setup, then the registry root key without suffix maps to a 32-bit view of registry.

Comment: After reading your comment on GitHub I changed HKLM to HKLM64 and it worked. I thought on 64 bit machine HKLM is treated as HKLM64??

Comment: It is, but only if you use [`64-bit mode of Inno Setup`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls). If you don't use 64-bit mode, `HKLM` maps to a 32-bit registry view.